# What is Ratchet for

Tags: mobile

I ran into http://maker.github.com/ratchet

As I see this is for prototyping and not actual production frontend for mobile.

Sorry for the stupid question, but is ratchet for a production website or just for pretending to have a mobile app?

Comment: You're right, it's for prototyping a mobile app using HTML.

Comment: why would you need to prototype this?

Comment: Because you can quickly and easily put together a nice looking base to work from when building a native app. Or it could be used to demonstrate the layout/basic functions of a proposed app. I don't use it myself but can see that there are quite a few use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

Why would it be only for prototyping? There are lots of scenarios where you would want a web app that mimicks a native one in production, without ever planning to build a native version.

For starters, production time is much lower when you can use html/javascript instead of Objective C, you can develop on any platform, skip the hassle of App Store approval and most functionality for non-timecritical apps is available as a web app. If you decide on going "real app" later you can wrap your web app in Phonegap and release it through the app store.